# Where is the official location to conduct feature requests?

Tags: bugs

I often have moments where I have improvement ideas for the Android OS, but don't know where to direct those suggestions.  What forum, group, mail list, site, app, etc. is used for official feature requests for the Android OS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Android Bug Report](http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html) system.

[Search to see if someone has already suggested the feature](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/advsearch), then submit your idea using the [feature request template](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request).

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I could have positively identified this as the correct location on my own.  The Android community seems a bit diluted by all the clone websites out there.

Comment: Well, `android.com` is the official Android domain, although it's primarily for developers.